# fileuploadfield in Extjs 3.4

Tags: php, extjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload files in Extjs 3.4 and php... but I cannot get it... all textfield can be sent (I watch firebug to demonstrate it) and I realized the fileuploadfield is not sent to php file that generate a Json... here is my code:

```
this.formAdd = new Ext.Panel({
            fileUpload:true,
            border:false,
            items:[{
                layout:'absolute', xtype:'form', border:true, width:490, height:300, id:'actividadPer', name:'actividadPer', bodyStyle:'padding-bottom:10px;',
                url:'jr_dirweb_store.php', 
                defaults:{ layout:'form',labelWidth: 50, labelAlign:'top', bodyStyle:'padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px', border:false },
                items:[
                    { x:0, y:10, items:[{ xtype:'textfield', fieldLabel:'<b>URL</b>', width:460, name:'txtUrl', itemId:'txtUrl',id:'txtUrl',allowBlank:false, vtype:'url',emptyText:'http://' }] },
                    { x:0, y:60, items:[{ xtype:'textfield', fieldLabel:'<b>Etiquetas (Español)</b>', width:460, name:'tagses', itemId:'tages',id:'tagses',allowBlank:false }] },
                    { x:0, y:110, items:[{ xtype:'textfield', fieldLabel:'<b>Tags (English)</b>', width:460, name:'tagsen', itemId:'tagsen',id:'tagsen',allowBlank:false }] },
                    { x:0, y:160, items:[{ xtype: 'fileuploadfield', emptyText: '<?=Title_seleccionar?>', fieldLabel:'<b><?=Title_imagen?></b>', name: 'iconox',id: 'iconox', buttonText:'<?=Title_examinar?>', width:460, allowBlank: false}]},
                    { x:0, y:210, items:[{ xtype:'combo', id:'idiomax', fieldLabel:'<b><?=Title_idioma?></b>', forceSelection: true, store: store_combo_cats, width: 150, triggerAction: 'all', editable:false, valueField:'id', displayField:'leng', lastQuery: ''}]},
                    { x:200, y:210, items:[{ xtype:'combo', name:'plataformax', id:'plataformax', fieldLabel:'<b><?=Title_junior81?></b>', forceSelection: true, store:store_combo_apps, width: 150, 
    triggerAction: 'all', editable:false, valueField:'id', displayField:'nombre', mode:'local'}]}

                ],
                guardar:function(){
                    if (Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().isValid()) { // Validamos el formulario
                        Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().submit({ url: 'jr_dirweb_store.php', method: 'POST', params:{pedido:'agregar'},
                            success: function(form, action){ 
                                alert(Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().getCmp('txtUrl').getValue());
                                Ext.example.msg('<?=Title_guardado?>','<?=Title_adminwebteca16?>'); 
                                Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().reset();
                                ventanaW.ventNew.close();
                                storegrid.removeAll();
                                storegrid.reload();
                            },
                            failure:function(form, action){
                                Ext.example.msg('<?=Title_error?>','Error'); 
                                Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().reset();  
                            }
                        });
                    }else{ Ext.example.msg('<?=Title_informacion?>','<?=Title_adminwebteca15?>'); }
                }
            }]
        }); 
        var ob=this;        
        this.ventNew = new Ext.Window({
            resizable   : false, //no se puede redimensionar
            title:'<?=Title_junior80?>',width:500,height:350, plain:true, bodyStyle:'background:#FFF;', modal:true, items:[this.formAdd],
            buttons:[                       
                        {
                            text:'<?=Title_guardad?>',
                            handler:function(){ 
                                Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').guardar(); 
                            }
                        }
                    ]
        }).show();
```

Comment: Ignore this line please:
alert(Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().getCmp('txtUrl').getValue());

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also pass enctype parameter in submit() method.

```
`Ext.getCmp('actividadPer').getForm().submit({ url: 'jr_dirweb_store.php', method: 'POST',enctype : 'multipart/form-data', params:{pedido:'agregar'}`,
 sucess:function(form,action){
    -----------------
    ------------------
 },
 failure:function(error,action){
     -----------------
     ------------------
 }
});
```

Comment: I did it, but it does not work.... how you can see in the image, "iconox" (name and id of fileuploadfield) is not sent in the post: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140904041444170041.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution: https://quizzpot.com/forum/questions/subir-un-archivo-al-servidor-con-extjs

It works!